# Is HTTPS upload over post form multpart as secure as SFTP?

Tags: ftp, sftp, multipartform-data, ftps, ftp-server

Our client needs to upload their database to the server and it looks like it is impossible to create a SFTP connection in JavaScript and FTP is not secure (and FTPS has issues).

Is using a HTTPS connection and posting a multipart form a viable alternative to SFTP?

Comment: More appropriate for http://security.stackexchange.com/ if you need proper security evaluation, but in short yes, if you use reasonable algorithms for HTTPS.

Comment: If we are running in the browser then we are subject to the algorithms the browser uses for HTTPS requests correct? If appropriate you may migrate this question.

Comment: Yes. If you are running up-to-date browser and http(s) server with reasonable certificates, you should be good. There is no automatic migration to Security, probably for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is HTTPS upload over post form multpart as secure as SFTP?

If you have up-to-date browser, up-to-date server (setup to accept reasonable algorithms) and reasonable certificate (that validates) the HTTPS is secure the same way as SFTP is (using reasonable algorithms in SSH and properly validating host keys).

Transferring files is secure as transferring any other confidential information using HTTPS (the banks/card payment services do that all the time).